# How centre of projection and vanishing point are same?

Tags: projective-geometry, projection

We know that in **perspective projection** Object positions are transformed to the view plane along lines that converge to the projection reference (center) point Which is like this:[image]

But many websites saying that COP(Centre of projection) and vanishing point both are same. But we know that Parallel lines that are not parallel to the viewing
plane, converge to a vanishing point vanishing point. In the above picture if I draw the parallel line through the point $A, B, C$ then they are intersects at infinity which is vanishing point.

My question is how COP and vanishing point both are same?

Comment: "But many websites saying that COP(Centre of projection) and vanishing point both are same." Can you direct us to one of those sites (preferably one that isn't a video)? It sounds like either you are visiting garbage web sites, or you misread something, but we can't tell which until we see what you saw.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/154334/169874, https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/12263/2911, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4282080/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).